# Coldfusion replace() not working on xml imported text

Tags: xml, replace, coldfusion

I'm pulling in an XML feed from a third party website.  The description field from the feed contains a lot of special characters.  When I run the Replace tag on the text it doesn't change anything.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong.  I've tried running the same code and typing in one of the words from the feed and the replace happens successfully.  I've also tried using DeMoronize from cflib and it doesn't change anything.

```
<CFHttp url="http://somewebsite.com/myfeed.xml" method="get">
<cfset mydoc = XmlParse(CFHTTP.FileContent) />

<cfloop from="1" to="#ArrayLen(mydoc.venues.xmlchildren)#" index="i" >  
<cfoutput>
    <cfset description = '#mydoc.venues.event[i].description.xmltext#'>

    Raw Description:    #description#<br/>

    Alt Description 1:  #Replace(description, "’", "'", "all" )#<br/>

    Alt Description 2:  #Replace(description, chr(180), "'", "all" )#<br/>

</cfoutput> <br/><hr/><br/> 
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Most likely the character(s) you are attempting to change is(are) not the character(s) you think it is(they are). Can you share an example of the description text from your XML data?

Comment: When in doubt, look at your data.  In this case, find a small string with the character in question, and dump each character in that string along with it's ascii code.  ColdFusion has an asc() function.  Also, for the code you posted, put that in a <pre> block or textarea so you get a better view of what's happening.

Comment: " Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong."? No. Not with the info provided. But, firstly, let's disabuse the situation of one false flag: CFML's `replace()` function works fine. That's not the problem. It's *your usage of it* that isn't working. What you need to do is to come up with a portable repro case that demonstrates your problem, removing as many tangential factors as possible. This should always be part of your troubleshooting process (see http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/short-self-contained-correct-compilable.html and linked docs for discussion).

Comment: NB: if you're using non-ASCII chars like "’", you'll need to tell CF to compile your CFM file using an appropriate char encoding. But given you seem to be trying to deal with weirdo MS chars, this is unlikely to help, given the non-standardness of the chars to begin with. You might want to verify the char codes of the characters you wish to swap out, rather than depend on the `demoronize()` approach.

Comment: Thank you Dan Bracuk.  I used the asc() function and found out it was chr(8217).  You would not believe how much frustration you have saved!

Comment: If this is the solution that solved the problem, you should add it as an answer